# apexcharts: HH:mm gets parsed to round number

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

I'm facing issues using Vue & ApexCharts. My application uses over a dozen charts, all working as expected, but like always, the final chart is giving me a rough time.

Here's an example of the series i assign to my stacked barchart:

Series (console log output):

```
[{"name":"project1","data":["09:34","08:18",0,"09:30","06:44","08:35","08:40","07:53","04:35",0,"09:34","08:44"]},{"name":"project2","data":[0,0,"07:20",0,0,0,0,0,0,"01:00",0,0]},{"name":"project3","data":[0,0,0,"08:30","08:30","05:30","08:28",0,0,0,0,0]}]
```

However, the time data is displayed as a round number in my chart.
When logging the chart out, i noticed my the arrays are then in the form of:

```
series: (3) […]
​​
0: (12) […]
​​​
0: 9
​​​
1: 8
​​​
2: 0
​​​
3: 9
​​​
4: 6
​​​
5: 8
​​​
6: 8
​​​
7: 7
​​​
8: 4
​​​
9: 0
​​​
10: 9
​​​
11: 8
```

It seems that somewhere between assinging the data and displaying it, the format `HH:mm` get's lost and parsed to a round number.

I've searched the entire docs, but nothing seems to be in lign with the desired result, having the `HH:mm` as tooltip and Y-axis label

I hope someone has some insights to share.

Thank you

Comment: have a look here https://apexcharts.com/docs/datetime/

Comment: Thanks but i've tried all those options already, not success

Comment: did you tried `options.yaxis.decimalsInFloat` also ? maybe you applied them on wrong axis, did you do it both on x and y ?

Comment: @yaya yes, tried it all. I can't get the y-axis to show the `HH:mm` data section.